# loading dropdown value from $getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a form with dropdowns and the page uses Knockout JS to bind data to html elements I have the below code to pre populate values from the database.

JS

```
    self.Irr = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.Crp = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.Incr = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.Brnd = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.Sec4 = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.getJSON("GetIrr", null, function (data) { self.Irr(data); })
        .done(function () {
            $.getJSON("GetCrp", null, function (data) { self.Crp(data); });
        })
        .done(function () {
            $.getJSON("GetTill", null, function (data) { self.Sec4(data); });
        })
        .done(function () {
            $.getJSON("GetBrnd", null, function (data) { self.Brnd(data); });
        })
        .done(function () {
            $.getJSON("GetIncr", null, function (data) { self.Incr(data); });
        })
        .done((function () {
            var request = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "UserSavedData",
                data: { "InfoVal": $("#infoID").val() }
            });


            request.success(function (result) {

    // here i use the result data to get ids of the dropdown values and
    //fill the form

}
```

The data from the observable array does not get populated(unable to assign the result id object as the getjson respnonse needs more time to load I guess)due to network timing of the $getJSON calls how do I handle this

As per the suggestions I used the **then()** instead of **done()** but still having issues with data not being able to load(the one field that does not populate does show up when I place a break point and debug in chrome but when not debugging it doesnt show the value)

Answer (score 3):

If you want your promises to chain sequentially, you need to use the `.then()` method and make sure you return any new promises from the success handlers in order to make them chainable.

```
$.getJSON('first')
  .then(function(){
     return $getJSON('second');
   })
   .then(function(){
     return $.getJSON('third');
   });
```

The code you have now will run all at once as soon as the first call is "done" because you aren't really chaining the promises, you are just adding a bunch of success handlers to the first promise.

**Below is an example** that shows the difference between the two approaches.

```js
(function(){

  function sayHelloAsync(msg){
    var def = jQuery.Deferred();
    
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("<div>" + msg + "</div>").appendTo("#messages");
      def.resolve();
    }, getRandomInt(300, 1500));
    
    return def.promise();
  }
  
  function clearMessages(){
    $("#messages").html('');
  }
  
  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
  
  function allAtOnce(){
    clearMessages();
    
    sayHelloAsync("first")
    .done(function(){
      sayHelloAsync("second");
    })
  .done(function(){
      sayHelloAsync("third");
    })
  .done(function(){
      sayHelloAsync("fourth");
    });
  }
  
  function ordered(){
    clearMessages();
    
    sayHelloAsync("first")
    .then(function(){
      return sayHelloAsync("second");
    })
  .then(function(){
      return sayHelloAsync("third");
    })
  .then(function(){
      return sayHelloAsync("fourth");
    });
  }

  $("#allAtOnce").on('click', allAtOnce);
  $("#ordered").on('click', ordered);
  
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="allAtOnce" type="button">All At Once</button>
<button id="ordered" type="button">Ordered</button>
<h2>Messages</h2>
<div id="messages">
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer. Perhaps using a random timeout length in the `setTimeout` call inside `sayHelloAsync` would better demonstrate that many calls to $.getJSON will return in random order.

Comment: @csum - Good suggestion. Made the change to use random timeouts.

Comment: This works a few times but when I try to refresh the page or redirect back to the page it will still not populate(just one field) but when i try to debug in chrome and place a breakpoint I can see that the ID is being placed in the selected observable. Guess when I have the break point on it it gets more time to load the data

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Josh.

A more Knockout-y way would be to have each observable [`subscribe`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) to the observable it depends on (note that you can just pass the observableArray as the success function, you don't need to wrap it).

```
self.Irr = ko.observableArray([]);
self.Crp = ko.observableArray([]);
self.Incr = ko.observableArray([]);
self.Brnd = ko.observableArray([]);
self.Sec4 = ko.observableArray([]);

$.getJSON("GetIrr", null, self.Irr);
self.Irr.subscribe(function () {
    $.getJSON("GetCrp", null, self.Crp);
});
self.Crp.subscribe(function () {
    $.getJSON("GetTill", null, self.Sec4);
});
```

etc.